# Using parametrized role in ansible - role configuration files

Tags: linux, ansible

I have made an ansible playbook which rolls out a complete JBoss-EAP 6 application (so, software, configuration of datasources, databases, the works). All runs fine but I have constructions like

```
- { role: instance, 
          bind_address: "{{ ansible_eth1.ipv4.address }}", 
          instance_type: standalone-ha, 
          port_offset: 0,  
          instance_name: test, 
          scanner_name: postnl, 
          lbl_group: testcluster, 
          admin_user: jbossadmin, 
          admin_password: "Welkom01!", 
          java_memory_min: 256m, 
          java_memory_max: 256m, 
          java_memory_perm: 256m }
```

in my playbook. This works fine, but in this question I am looking to a cleaner way to define the variables (of course there is the groups_var directory, in which you can put these variables, but this isn't going to work when you need two or more instances.

So is there a way to clean this up, like so:

```
  - {role: instance, role_vars: /opt/test.cfg }
```

or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use host_var to define your var.

Another method is to use conditional import 
here is an example if include and fall back to defaults.yml

> vars_files: 
>        - [ "{{ ansible_os_distribution }}".yml,  'defaults.yml' ]

Hope that helps